# How to create a size bar in seaborn for bubble chart?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, charts, seaborn

I've created a bubble chart which is shown below. I need to create a size bar, showing value and it's corresponding bubble's size.[image] 
The code used for creating this bubble chart.

```
sns.scatterplot(y='yvar', x='xvar', hue='huevar', data=data_gp,
                 s= data_gp['size_var'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn does this automatically when using the `size` argument.

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip",
                      hue="size", size="size",
                      data=tips)
```

[image]

(Code and picture directly copied from the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html))